# Mule 4 SFTP delete does the deletion but still throws the error file does not exist

Tags: file, sftp, mule4

I have a scenario where I am listing the files in SFTP directory. For each file, I am archiving the file to a different location and then doing SFTP delete. The file actually gets deleted successfully from SFTP location but in error I still see below error. Any idea why this would be happening?

```
ERROR 2021-11-11 02:30:55,463 [[MuleRuntime].io.03: [sys-radial].external-radial-sftp-inbound-router--SFTP-Delete-subflow.BLOCKING @31470249] [event: 2ae4cdc0-4269-11ec-8be8-006f0000086f] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorContinueHandler: 

--------------------------------------------
Message               : Path '/Inbox/BHBNA_BHBUS_ROMShpmntCntrDtls_20211014214251.xml' doesn't exist.
Element               : external-radial-sftp-inbound-router--SFTP-Delete-subflow/processors/0 @ sys-radial:shared-radial-connectivity/external-radial-sftp-inbound-router.xml:30 (Delete Remote File)
Element XML           : <sftp:delete doc:name="Delete Remote File" doc:id="927f78f9-feb6-462f-8a08-34c73c9b5548" config-ref="External_Radial_SFTP_Config" path="#['${external_sftp.radial.inbound_dir}' ++ vars.filename.^raw]"></sftp:delete>
Error type            : SFTP:ILLEGAL_PATH
Payload Type          : org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Path '/Inbox/BHBNA_BHBUS_ROMShpmntCntrDtls_20211014214251.xml' doesn't exist
    at org.mule.runtime.extension.api.exception.ModuleException.<init>(ModuleException.java:66)
```

Comment: Version of Mule and SFTP connector? Are deploying the application to multiple workers or a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Please check which version of SFTP you are using. Probably you would be using the outdated version. Try to update it with the latest version (1.4.1). I'm sharing the link for release notes as well:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/connector-sftp